# Send array json to controller web api c#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller, but i got the object **myJson** null.

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Torneo/AddEquipos")]
    public JsonResult InsertTorneoEquipos([FromBody]EquiposTorneo myJson)
    {
     
        return new JsonResult("OK");

    }
```

I send this object json in my front-end

```
myJson = 

    [
    {\"id_torneo\":1,\"id_equipo\":27},{\"id_torneo\":1,\"id_equipo\":28}
    ]
```

Model EquiposTorneo

```
  public class EquiposTorneo
    {
        public int id_torneo { get; set; }

        public int id_equipo { get; set; }

    }
```

My front-end vuejs:

```
   registrar () {
        const params = this.rowData
        const myJson = JSON.stringify(params)

        axios.post(url + 'Torneo/AddEquipos', {
          myJson,
        })
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try following.

```
[FromBody]List<EquiposTorneo> myJson
```

If there is single item then single object and if array then List or Enumrable required.